# Handling optional function arguments

Tags: python

Say you have a function that accepts one or more optional arguments. What is the best way to approach this?

Here is a function where I have two arguments that are mandatory, and one optional which changes the output:

```
def get_cases(**kwargs):
    """Returns a list of test cases for a test suite or specific section in a test suite."""
    if 'section_id' not in kwargs:
        req = requests.get(settings.URL + 'get_cases/' + str(kwargs['project_id']) +
                           '&suite_id=' + str(kwargs['suite_id']),
                           auth=(settings.USR, settings.PWD), headers=headers)
    else:
        req = requests.get(settings.URL + 'get_cases/' + str(kwargs['project_id']) +
                           '&suite_id=' + str(kwargs['suite_id']) +
                           '&section_id=' + str(kwargs['section_id']),
                           auth=(settings.USR, settings.PWD), headers=headers)
    return req.json()
```

I am using **kwargs to capture all values and then if the optional value is present in the dictionary then I perform a different action.

Besides the redundancy in the code above (2 duplicate lines), is there a better way to approach the handling of optional arguments? I am not too fussed about the duplicate lines at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments): (you can replace `None` with a different value if `None` may be passed). If section_id can be *anything, then set section_id to a special object instead of `None` (you can use `object()` to generate an object) (successive calls of `object()` are not equal as the memory address is different).

```
def get_cases(some_args, another_arg, section_id=None):
    if section_id is None:
        # A value for section_id wasn't passed.
    else:
        # An value for section_id was passed.
```

<sub>^ passing the special object using my solution will make the code think that the argument was not passed</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this solution is exactly what I was looking for and is very easy to read/understand.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, I'd use a dictionary to build up the query string.

```
import urllib
def get_cases(project_id, **kwargs):
    qs = urllib.urlencode(kwargs)
    url = settings.URL + 'get_cases/' + project_id + "?" + qs
    req = requests.get(url, auth=(settings.USR, settings.PWD), headers=headers))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_cases(**kwargs):    
     req = requests.get(settings.URL + 'get_cases/' + str(kwargs['project_id']) +
            '&suite_id=' + str(kwargs['suite_id']) +
            ('' if 'section_id' not in kwargs else '&section_id=' + str(kwargs['section_id'])),
            auth=(settings.USR, settings.PWD), headers=headers)
    return req.json()
```